# SQL Server Database Schemas

Tags: database, database-design

I use schemas in my databases, but other than the security benefits and the fact that my OCD is happy, I don't really know whay it is good practice to use them. Besides the more granular security, are there other reasons for using schemas when building a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary pupose of schemas is indeed security. A secondary benefit is that they act like namepaces for your application tables and objects, thus allowing a conflict free side-by-side deployment with other applications that may use same names for its object.

Answer (score 1):

Schema's arose from the original Sql Server.  They didn't have schemas which meant that every single object in the database had to be owned by someone.  If jill from accounting left the company then you had to manually reassign all her stuff to someone else etc.  Schemas now own objects and users belong to schemas, which makes all the DB Admins very happy people :).

Basically you can have users leave and you remove their privileges by removing them from schemas and deleting the user.  Adding privileges to a user is now as simple as adding the user to the schema.